# Two weeks have past, still nothing on my transactions

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, mac

Two weeks have past, still nothing, can anybody advise? tried the zap wallet thing, and its just removed the transactions, so theres nothing in my wallet on my mac. the only thing i have to go on is the bitcoin link:

https://blockchain.info/tx/44c784d8f82d962103ffdf5d463a1460150a21cc67a0750d4a3f6a35a0d18d9a?show_adv=true

Comment: The fee on that transaction is absurdly low for current network conditions. It would need to be about ten times higher.

Comment: Are you sender or recipient of that transaction?

Comment: im the sender to https://www.bitstamp.net/ where i want to withdraw

Comment: i realise the fee is too low, i didnt understand the whole fee thing until after - willing to pay to get this through

Comment: hi David, what are my options, how can i get this through? i will pay to get this push through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already tried "-zapwallettxes", your client is now no longer broadcasting this transaction.
You have four choices(I listed them after difficulty):

**1**. Wait until it gets dropped from mempool or picked up by a miner.

**2**. Ask miners for help.
Since you are in urgent need: [bitcointalk.org have plenty of members providing free transaction accelerator services.](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=52.0) You can also go for the paid services, but be aware don't fall for the scammy ones.

**3**. Attempting a [Replace-By-Fee (RBF) double spend transaction.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

**4**. Attempt a C[hild-Pays-For-Parent transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) if you are also the recipient of this transaction.

Comment: thank you - i will try and pay someone to help - if you know of a genuine service, any help or suggestions would be very much welcomed - thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

I’ve done three transction of btc to my exchange wallet and it been 12 days and still no confirmation
My address are https://blockchain.info/address/3C6FMy8BFeCbVRd7457eBTFoYGQirna1Y3

https://blockchain.info/address/3FYUHdqEQ5Sg7mkMBtyQbUSfJgDbhTejUt

https://blockchain.info/address/3368APnw4u3b18ediJYerdyAA4fcfh5ztE

Please help me im really desperate. I cant afford to loose that much amount

Comment: this is not an answer on the questions.